# TcpDump. Как посмотреть трафик, приходящий на определенный порт?

Tags: centos, tcp, трафик, tcpdump

Есть симулятор устройства передачи геоданных, работающего по TCP/IP. Этот симулятор расположен на удаленном сервере и посылает данные на определенную машину через сеть интернет (используя ip + port). Заказчик сказал, что настроит симулятор так, чтобы он присылал на наш сервер сообщения на определенный порт. Мне же нужно как-то посмотреть, проходит ли какой-то трафик по этому порту или нет.

Сервер работает на CentOS. Системный администратор сказал, что открыл наружу порт и прокинул на эту машину. Пытаюсь использовать tcpdump. Ввожу команду:

```
# tcpdump port 9000
```

На что я вижу в консоли:

> tcpdump: NFLOG link-layer type filtering not implemented

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно сделать, чтобы узнать, есть ли трафик по определенному номеру порта. В системном администрировании не силен.

Comment: Укажите tcpdump на каком сетевом устройстве трафик слушать `tcpdump -i имя-вашей-внешней-сетевухи port 9000`

Comment: Можно использовать wireshark для наглядности

Comment: @Mike спасибо за ответ! Подскажите, пожалуйста: как узнать имя нужного сетевого устройства на CentOS?

Comment: @Mike ввел `netstat -i` - вывело два интерфейса. Заиспользовал имя одного из них: `tcpdump -i ens33 port 9000`. Ответ от консоли такой: `tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on ens33, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes`. Как узнать, получил ли я хотя бы один пакет?

Comment: ifconfig без параметров покажет все интерфесы. выбирайте который больше похож на внешний (по ip например) вообще он скорее всего ethN или en-что-нибудь. если ifconfig нет, то `ip link`

Comment: это стартовая надпись она всегда есть. когда пакет прилетит он еще что нибудь напишет.

Comment: @Mike ничего не пишет. Спустя какое-то время я нажал ctrl+c - написало, что `0 packets captured, 3 packets received by filter, 0 packets dropped by kernel`. Как я понял, пришло 3 пакета на порт. Правильно я понимаю?

Comment: без порта напишите и убедитесь что там вообще трафик есть. просто пришли некие пакеты но они не на 9000 порт были

Comment: @Mike попробовал - трафик есть

Comment: ну вот вы увидели как выглядит трафик. когда на 9000 порт что нибудь прилетит то должны быть вот такие же данные

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112553/discussion-between-andrei-khotko-and-mike).

Comment: @Mike перенес в чат обсуждение. Не желаете оформить ответ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В комментариях [@Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike) привел правильный синтаксис команды. Нужно было указать имя сетевого устройства. В итоге, команда выглядит следующим образом:

```
tcpdump -i ens33 port 9000
```